# Can't add to $index

Tags: knockout.js

In a foreach loop when i try to access the index

```
<!-- ko foreach: availableList-->

    <span data-bind="text: $index">
<!-- /ko -->
```

it works fine. But when i try to add to the index like

```
<span data-bind="text: $index + 1">
```

it displays `function c(){if(0<arguments.length)return c.equalityComparer&&c.equalityComparer(d,arguments[0])||(c.O(),d=arguments[0],c.N()),this;a.i.lb(c);return d}2`

i tried to parseInt the index but it returns NaN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$index` will be being treated like any other observable - ie as a function.  You'll need to call it if you want to manipulate the returned value, rather than binding to it directly:

```
<span data-bind="text: $index() + 1">
```